# How to print null values in python if a text is not found in HTML page?

Tags: python, html, regex, xml, list

I need a way to render a null value and append it to a list in python when text is missing from an Html page.

The raw data rendered in Html is as follows:

```
  <BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">TICKER: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">FB (NASDAQ) (57%); </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c4">AXP</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> (NYSE) (54%)</SPAN></P>
    </DIV>
  <BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">INDUSTRY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">NAICS511110 NEWSPAPER PUBLISHERS (61%); SIC2711 NEWSPAPERS: PUBLISHING, OR PUBLISHING &amp;</SPAN></P>
  </DIV>
  <BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LOAD-DATE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">November 7, 2016</SPAN></P>
<!-- Hide XML section from browser
</DOCFULL>
    </DOC> -->
    <DIV CLASS="c10">&nbsp;</DIV>
    <A NAME="DOC_ID_0_2"></A><!-- Hide XML section from browser
    <DOC NUMBER=3>
    <DOCFULL> -->
    <BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">TICKER: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">CS (PAR) (91%); AXJ (ASX) (91%); AXA (BIT) (91%); </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c4">AXP</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> (NYSE) (57%)</SPAN></P>
    </DIV>
    <BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">COUNTRY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">UNITED KINGDOM (88%)</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">United Kingdom GB</SPAN></P>
    </DIV>
    <BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">REGION: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Europe; EU; Western Europe</SPAN></P>
    </DIV>
    <BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LOAD-DATE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">May 12, 2016</SPAN></P>
```

I need to write the text values in-between the tags, which are; `TICKER`, `INDUSTRY`, `COUNTRY`, `REGION` and `LOAD-DATE` into two separate lists.

- Set 1 needs to contain `TICKER`, `INDUSTRY` and `LOAD-DATE`.
- Set 2 needs to contain `COUNTRY` and `REGION`.

If `COUNTRY` is missing from the text, I need to append an entry containing a `Null` value to the corresponding list.

Example

- The first Html tag list doesn't contain `COUNTRY`, and so `NULL` should be stored
- The second Html tag list does contain `COUNTRY`, and so `United Kingdom` should be stored.

The resulting should become:

```
['Null', 'United Kingdom\nUnited Kingdom GB']
```

Solutions I have tried are as follows:

```
countrypattern="\<SPAN CLASS=\"c8\"\>COUNTRY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS=\"c2\"\>(.*)\</SPAN>"
countrypatternvalues=[a.strip("*") for a in re.findall(countrypattern,response)]
if not countrypatternvalues:
     countrypatternvalues.append(None)
countryvalues = re.sub(cleanr, '', str(countrypatternvalues))
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: That HTML is *horrible*. Why all caps? Why have BR before each DIV?

Comment: But nevertheless, you should definitely *not* be trying to use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In that case, can you pls help me with the right solution for my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
import re

res = re.findall(r"""<SPAN CLASS="c8">([A-Z]+): *</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">([^<]*)</SPAN>""",html)

class Items(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # list of items
        self.items = []             

    def add_item(self, name, value):
        if (not self.items) or (name in self.items[-1]):
            self.items.append({})
        self.items[-1][name] = value

    def get_list(self, key):
        return [ item[key] if key in item else None for item in self.items ]         


items = Items()

for item in res:
    items.add_item(item[0], item[1])

print items.get_list('COUNTRY')
```

This works if there is no duplicates of names in groups, because duplication spawn another group.

Comment: It is not appending null values to my output

Comment: Now class `Items` implements `get_list` method, that returns list of values for a given key (with number of values == number of items).

Answer (score 0):

I have edited a jsFiddle I found to give you an example of how this can be done using `split(':')`

http://jsfiddle.net/4XumV/29/

Comment: I dont' understand exactly. Is this answer to my question?

Comment: It is a starting point.  You can simply get the innerHTML of all spans inside a parent element, check if they are empty or not, and then either add the values to your array with the split(':')[1] or add 'NULL' to your array if its empty.